# Why js privates (#field) are polyfilled on angular build?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to use js [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_properties) in my angular (v17) app created with angular cli. I used target = ES2022 in the tsconfig, but after the build I noticed that my private field is poly-filled with a WeakMap. I want to know the reason why it happens.

```
ng new my-brand-new-app

@Component({
...
})
export class AppComponent {
  #hello = 'hello';
  title = this.#hello;
}

ng build
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have a `.browserslist` config that targets browsers that don't support private fields.

The Angular CLI uses browserslist to downlevel your code syntax to match the required browsers.

By default (= if none provided) Angular uses the following config:

```
last 2 Chrome versions
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
```

I not sure why but if you update the Safari entry with :

```
last 1 Safari major versions
last 1 iOS major versions
```

It fixes the issue.

Comment: That was my first thought, but no, I don't have .browserslist. As I mentioned I used ```ng new my-brand-new-app``` command and it doesn't create .browserslist.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that browserslist is used anyway during a build process. Now I found the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility) but indeed it's not clear why the default config doesn't work, because it ought to according to the [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=private%20field).